# How to store variable during all Spring based application lifetime?

Tags: java, spring

I develop Spring based Java Web Services. I need to generate UUID when application starts (application server startups the context) and keep it unchanged during lifetime of application. One or more of the service classes (with @Service) should access this variable. UUID may be changed only when context was restarted (redeploy of application or restarting of application server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a regular singleton, just make it use `class="java.util.UUID" factory-method="randomUUID"`. Refer to it from other beans as usual.

Comment: Nice idea. Would have adviced something similar. But your way is more elegant. +1